# How can I find the definitions for the -k, -e, and -p flags of ktutil addent?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line, kerberos

I'm replacing a developer on a project & trying to understand their code:

```
$ ktutil 
ktutil: addent -password -p $userName@$domainName -k 1 -e rc4-hmac
Password for <$userName>@<$domainName>:
```

That command creates an entry which can be seen here:

```
$ ktutil
ktutil: l
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ------------------------------------------
   1    1              <$userName>@<$domainName>
```

## What I've tried

`$ man ktutil` which shows:

[image]

```
$ ktutil
ktutil: addent -h
usage: addent (-key | -password) -p principal -k kvno -e enctype
ktutil: addent ?
usage: addent (-key | -password) -p principal -k kvno -e enctype
```

I found this: [ktutil-latest doc](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/admin_commands/ktutil.html#add-entry):
[image]

Comment: The `ktutil` manual refers to the manual for `kadmin`. Did you already look there?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeah I did, but I wasn't sure who the flags in my code actually belong to. So are you saying the flags in my code could be from the flags defined in the kadmin manual?

Comment: No. Since you're asking about what the `-k`, `-e`, and `-p` options of `ktutil` do, I proposed that you look at the `kadmin` manual, where these options seems to be better documented. I'm not saying that `ktutil` takes the same options as `kadmin` but that the set of options that seems to overlap between the two utilities, that seem to have the same meaning, may be have better documentation in the `kadmin` manual.  The options that you ask about belong to interactive commands used by `ktutil`, not to `kadmin`, but they may mean the same thing as in `kadmin`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Okay gotcha. Very clear now. You are most likely right, they do probably have the same or similar meaning but can't know for sure without any documentation from the interactive commands used by ktutil stating explicitly what those flags do. But at least I know who the options belong to now.

Comment: I'm not turning that into a real answer right now. Instead, I hope that someone with experience of those commands will answer with more authority than what I can muster.  You can also answer your own question if you feel confident enough to write something up that may be a help to future readers (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Kusalananda I wish I could thumbs up comments, thank you!